# how to compare a part of header file(fasta) and fit this to one file together?

Tags: awk, header, compare, fasta

I have more `fasta` files in a directory that have the same beginning but different ends:

```
file1abgff
-----------

file2adferr
------------

file3adfr
----------

file1adcef
-----------
```

How to compare the beginning of all files with each another in a directory and fit the matches together to one new file (`example >file1abgffadcef`)?

Comment: Need more inputs to the OP, so that people can help you. Provide few sample files with valid headers and how would you like to get the output. The example you have provided is not helping!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code seems to solve your problem.

Suppose you have the input file:

```
cat input
>file1abgff
>file2adferr
>file3adfr
>file1adcef
```

Here is my solution:

```
 sed 's/[0-9]/& /' input | awk  '{a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1]"|"$2 : $0)}END{for (i in a){print a[i]}}' | sed 's/ //' | grep  "|" | sed 's/|//'

>file1abgffadcef
```

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk and you never need cat when you're using either one (google UUOC).

Comment: Hi, Babi and @EdMorton, I have improved my solution.

Comment: Hi ginkgo, thanks for your answer! But this doesn't work. With this code I have the output: >file3adfradfr

Comment: Maybe anyone have a idea to help me, I try in a other way:
 #!/bin/bash
TESTCHARS=6 
for i in *; do
    for j in *; do
        
  if [[  `head  -c$TESTCHARS "$i"` = `head  -c$TESTCHARS "$j"`]]; 
 
 then cat i j > /combinedfile.fasta #this part doesn't work
            
        fi
    done
done
exit 0